# javascript object transfer

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to transfer a javascript object from one runtime(can be browser) to another?

of course I can seralize the oject to string and eval() it on the other machine, but is there more efficient way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of **[JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html)** for transferring object.

Comment: I am looking for something more efficient , is it more efficient?

Comment: hi json is better than xmls so i think nothing is better than it